# Enqueue jsPDF in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, jspdf

I enqueue my jsPDF and the file which is dependent on it as

```
wp_enqueue_script('jsPDF','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js', array(), '2.5.1', false);
```

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-plugin-pro', plugins_url('assets/js/my-plugin-pro.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array('jsPDF'), MY_PLUGIN_PRO_VERSION, false);
```

And use that in the my-plugin-pro.js file as

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.my_plugin_export_pdf_btn', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (typeof jsPDF !== 'undefined') {
            // jsPDF is available, let's create a PDF
            const doc = new jsPDF();
            doc.text('Hello, this is a test PDF created using jsPDF!', 10, 10);
            doc.save('test.pdf');
        } else {
            // jsPDF is not available
            console.error('jsPDF is not available!');
        }
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

But I get the following error:

```
my-plugin-pro.js?ver=5.2.1:394 jsPDF is not available!
(anonymous) @   wmy-plugin-pro.js?ver=5.2.1:394
dispatch    @   jquery.js?ver=3.7.1:5145
elemData.handle @   jquery.js?ver=3.7.1:4949
```

Comment: "but in javascript I get following error: jsPDF library is not available" - where are you getting that error, in your browser's console? Is that the exact error? Can you determine which line of code is causing that error specifically?

Comment: @ChrisHaas the error occurs in console. Following is the line
let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [1500, 1400]);

Comment: Remove the line `const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;`

and also use 

`const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [1500, 1400]);`
 
instead of 

`let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', [1500, 1400]);`

Comment: @b126 did not worked :(

Comment: Try to define the correct dependencies when enqueueing your script, like: `wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-analytify-pro', plugins_url( 'assets/js/wp-analytify-pro.js', dirname( __FILE__ ) ), array('jquery', 'jspdf'), ANALYTIFY_PRO_VERSION, true );` … … … … Also, as you are using jQuery with WordPress, you should include your script code in `jQuery( function($){ /* Here your code */ });`.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec jsPDF is installed using npm

Comment: "jsPDF is installed using npm" - Then why are you using the CDN version?

Comment: Issue is solved. I was enqueueing the script wrongly. Then somehow found a tutorial and it worked:
https://www.freakyjolly.com/multipage-canvas-pdf-using-jspdf/